# How to merge dataframes with Dask w/o memory error

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a question about Python Pandas and Dask.
I want to merge two huge DataFrames with index, but they are too big and I get a memory error.

*Exception has occurred: _ArrayMemoryError
Unable to allocate 25.5 GiB for an array with shape (3429113976,) and data type int64*

So I am trying dask for the first time, but I still get a memory error.
Below is the code I tried with Colab. The size is small, so dd.merge() at the bottom line is executed without any problem, but in the real environment, the same error occurs as with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.dataframe.multi import (
align_partitions,
_maybe_align_partitions,
)

lst_org = [['a',10,20,30,40],['b',11,21,31,41],['c',12,22,32,42],['d',13,23,33,43],['e',14,24,34,44]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(lst_org, columns=["name", "A", "B", "C", "D"])
df1 = df1.set_index('name')
print(df1)

lst_org = [['e',114,124,134,144],['a',110,120,130,140],['b',111,121,131,141],['c',112,122,132,142],['d',113,123,133,143]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(lst_org, columns=["name", "E", "F", "G", "H"])
df2 = df2.set_index('name')
print(df2)

# align_partitions(df1, df2)

ddf_m = dd.merge(df1, df2, how="outer", left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(ddf_m)
```

The [official document](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.multi.DataFrame.merge.html#dask.dataframe.multi.DataFrame.merge) says in Notes to do **align_partitions()**, so I ran it, but the result was the same.

In layman's terms, df1, df2 in `dd.merge(df1, df2, ...)` should be in dask format. but it is garbled in the first place. Perhaps ddf1 is not an entity.

```
ddf1 = dd.from_pandas(df1, npartitions=4)
print(ddf1)
> Dask DataFrame Structure:
> A B C D
> npartitions=2
> a int64 int64 int64 int64
> c ... ... ... ...
> e ... ... ... ...
> Dask Name: from_pandas, 2 tasks
```

I just want to merge a huge df, but I would like to know how to use dask.
Thank you.

Comment: I find that I need to do ddf.compute(). However it kills Windows10 due to memory shortage.

Comment: can you provide all the code that gets you to the memory error?

Comment: Did you convert `df1` and `df2` to `dask.dataframes` before merging them by`dd.merge(ddf1, ddf2, how="outer").compute()`? This works fine for me and should decrease run times depending on the number of partitions. You should definitely provide more information about your error.